# Delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times - realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, realloc

I've been doing some coding exercises for fun, and I've recently come across this challenge on codewars. My proposed solution is listed below, but it outputs an error:

> "realloc(): invalid next size" and also "Test Crashed - Caught
> unexpected signal: 6"

I don't know what's happening here, as the realloc seems completely fine to me. Any clues?

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* delete_nth(size_t szin, int order[szin], int max_e, size_t *szout) {

    int *arr = NULL, *temp, tms;
    size_t i,j;
    
    *szout = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < szin; i++) {
      tms = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < *szout; j++)
        if (arr[j] == order[i]) {
          tms++;
        }
        
      if (tms < max_e) {
        temp = realloc(arr, *szout + 1);
        if (temp == NULL) return NULL;
        arr = temp;
        arr[*szout] = order[i];
        (*szout)++;
      }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `if (temp == NULL) return NULL;` leaks memory. Do `if (temp == NULL) { free(arr); return NULL; }` `*szout + 1);` Did you forgot `* sizeof(int)`?

Comment: you're absolutely right. i don't know how i missed the * sizeof. thanks

Comment: `realloc` argument is the number of bytes, but you use it as if it were the number of ints